# How can i use angular 2 request data

Tags: angular, angular-http

When we send data including JSON content to an external  api, an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error occures. The solution of this problem is that using `x-www-form-urlencoded content`.
Is there anyway to use JSON instead ?

JSON content :

```
    this.http.post('/api/login', {
      email: email,
      password: pass
    }).map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      } , error => console.error(error));
  }
```

`x-www-form-urlencod`:

```
  this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, method: 'post'});
    return this.http.post('/api/login', "email=info@mail.com&password=123", this.options )
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map(user => {
            if (user) {
                console.log(user);
            }
            return !!user ;
        });
}
```

Other solution :

1.install Access-Control-Allow-Origin extension in Chrome
2.lunch web api in localhost bu looking for another way
3.enable CORS on IIS7

**but problem is not resolved !**

Comment: it is a CORS issue you need to enable it in your api

Comment: @RahulSingh CORS by web.config is enabled , the problem was not resolved

Comment: Check that in post man. 
By default /token is url to get token in mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebConfig :

```
 <httpProtocol> <customHeaders> <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> </customHeaders> </httpProtocol>​
```

WebApiConfig :

```
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load /api/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.